# PHP strtotime() with timezone

Tags: php

I have this date string `March 26, 2012`

I can get timestamp with `strtotime('March 26, 2012')`

But that would be timestamp of `March 26, 2012` in UTC zone.

I know I can use `DateTime`, but `'March 26, 2012'` is not a recognized input...

```
$date=new DateTime('March 26, 2012', new DateTimeZone('America/Toronto'));
$timestamp=$date->format('U');
```

So how can I get timestamp of 'March 26, 2012' Toronto time ?

Comment: `date_default_timezone_set`… But really, there is no UNIX timestamp for *a day*. It must be exact to the second. So at best you'll get the timestamp for *March 26, 2012, 00:00:00*…!?

Comment: Do you mean March 26, 2012 at 00:00:00 Toronto time (there's no time in your date here)?

Comment: And that value seems to work perfectly fine with `DateTime`: https://3v4l.org/gXj2j

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$d = DateTime::createFromFormat("F d, Y", 'March 26, 2012', new DateTimeZone("UTC"));
echo $d->format('d/m/Y');
```

[DateTime::createFromFormat](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) accept 3 parameters, format, time string and timezone.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `date_default_timezone_set('America/Toronto')` at the root of your application if everything is in Toronto time.

Also consider using [DateTime::createFromFormat](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) as you know the format you’re getting it in. The timezone is the third param.

```
DateTime::createFromFormat('M f, Y', $time, 'America/Toronto')
```